# SWF file on top of another SWF file

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have two flash file. One is first.fla and another one is pages.fla . In the first.fla file there is an image of cockpit. In the middle position there is a purple circle. In pages.fla file there is a green button in top right corner.

Now here is my problem...When i clicked on the purple button it should load another swf file named pages.swf. I loaded it. It works fine. Now when i clicked green button in the pages.swf file it should load first.swf file. It also loaded but not work properly. Some menu button are coming in front of first.swf file. I tried but could not remove it. I need to remove those menu button in front of the first.swf file.

Here are the [files...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hihrcjmfuyop3ri/work.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Your second button shouldn't be loading first.swf. It should simply hide pages.swf, as first.swf is already running.